# Static var in stuct sets back to default value

Tags: ios, swift, struct, static

I have a swift struct that has a static variable and it is set to a default value because there is no initalizer. When I set the value and then go to use it the value is always set back to its original place holder value. Here is the code. It is strange because it only happens for this one variable.

```
struct CrossData
{
    static var game:NumbaChuteGame = NumbaChuteGame(gameStyle: GameType.Addition, gameDifficulty: 1)
} //default value

 CrossData.game = NumbaChuteGame(gameStyle: gameType, gameDifficulty: difficulty
println(CrossData.game)
// still set to default value
```

Comment: Are you printing same variable ? `println(CrossData.Game)` ? In your code it is `CrossData.game` and in the print statement it is `CrossData.Game`

Comment: I am actually not printing it, but I put that there as an example. I am using the correct variable in my code.

Comment: What is `NumbaChuteGame` ?

Comment: A custom game class for the Sprite Kit game I am making